# mysql throws me an error with the IF what should I do?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
 create trigger TR_03
  before update
  on empleados
  for each row
 begin
  if updating('idempleado') then
   insert into controlCambio values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.idempleado, new.idempleado);
  end if;
  if updating('nombre') then
   insert into controlCambios values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.nombre, new.nombre);
  end if;
  if updating('documento') then
   insert into controlCambios values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.documento, new.documento);
  end if;
  if updating('cargo') then
   insert into controlCambios values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.cargo, new.cargo);
  end if;
 end TR_03;
```

Comment: What is `updating(stringvalue)` supposed to be?

Comment: a column of a table!

Comment: I am not aware of an "updating" function in MySQL, nor of a way for a user defined function to be able determine the update state of a field by a string indicating its name. As far as know, and can tell from context, you need to be doing something like `IF( NOT (old.idempleado <=> new.idempleado))`

Comment: What is the error you're getting? How is `updating` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You have it almost right your end TR_03 is not allowed in mysql.
And i also think that updating() is a fucntion in your database
so use

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger TR_03 
before update on empleados 
for each row 
begin 
  if updating('idempleado') then 
    insert into controlCambio values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.idempleado, new.idempleado); 
  end if; 
  if updating('nombre') then 
    insert into controlCambios values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.nombre, new.nombre);   
  end if; 
  if updating('documento') then 
    insert into controlCambios values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.documento, new.documento); 
  end if; 
  if updating('cargo') then 
    insert into controlCambios values("superusuarioalber",now(), old.cargo, new.cargo); 
  end if; 
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```